# elasticsearch how to boost according to a specific value

Tags: boost, elasticsearch

This is my index

```
PUT /testtest/
{
  "mappings" : {
    "docs" : {
      "properties" : {
        "field1" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },"field2" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to search for a specific value for `field1`, and then if the value of `field2` equals to a specific word (such as "swimming") i want to boost it more than the other words.

#### what I tried

```
 GET /bla bla/_search
{
  "query": {
      "match": {
        "field1": "value to search goes here"
      }, 
    "boosting": {
      "positive": {
        "term": {
          "field2": {
            "value": "values to positive boost goes here"
          }
        }
      },
      "negative": {
        "term": {
          "field2": {
            "value": "value to negative boost goes here"
          }
        }
      },
      "negative_boost": 0.5
    }
  }
}
```

but i got parse error for the query, i don'tk now if what i am doing is correct or not